# how to sum 2 or more Column in big database - c#

Tags: c#, sql, database

i use database MS Accsses with C# winForm.
i want to sum more than 2 dolumns in database using sql query or method
[for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHZQ3.png)

i tried this code. it works, but it's too slow.

```
 OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select *from Vol_rate  ");
        command.Connection = conn;
        OleDbDataReader dr = null;
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                R1 += int.Parse((dr["R1"].ToString()));
                R2 += int.Parse((dr["R2"].ToString()));
                R3 += int.Parse((dr["R3"].ToString()));
                R4 += int.Parse((dr["R4"].ToString()));
                R5 += int.Parse((dr["R5"].ToString()));
                R6 += int.Parse((dr["R6"].ToString()));
                R7 += int.Parse((dr["R7"].ToString()));
                R8 += int.Parse((dr["R8"].ToString()));
                R9 += int.Parse((dr["R9"].ToString()));
                R10 += int.Parse((dr["R10"].ToString()));
                R11 += int.Parse((dr["R11"].ToString()));
                R12 += int.Parse((dr["R12"].ToString()));
                R13 += int.Parse((dr["R13"].ToString()));
                R14 += int.Parse((dr["R14"].ToString()));
                R15 += int.Parse((dr["R15"].ToString()));

            }
        }
        catch { MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "خظأ"); }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        rate = R1 + R2 + R3 + R4 + R5 + R6 + R7 + R8 + R9 + R10 + R11 + R12 + R13 + R14 + R15;
        fullres = (season * vol) * 75;
        res = rate * 100.0 / fullres;
        circularProgressBar2.Text = String.Format("{0:0.0}", res);
        circularProgressBar2.Value = (int)res;

    }
```

how to calculate columns with smart and simple code?

Comment: "SELECT SUM(R1+R2+R3+R4+R5+R6+R7+R8+R9+R10+R11+R12+R13+R4+R15) as TotalAmount FROM whateveryourtableisnamed"

Comment: thanks,, it's work :D

Comment: I wonder if you can not read it directly as int from OleDbDataReader instead of parsing the string.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Those aren't strings, they're passed as object but you need to know the exact type, as those can be Int32, Int64, Double or whatever the DB has used. But as anything has .ToString this trick is used widely (but it's extremely inefficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick by calculating everything in your database:

```
SELECT sum(R1 + R2 + R3 + R4 + R5 + R6 + R7 + R8 + R9 + R10 + R11 + R12 + R13 + R14 + R15) as total FROM Vol_rate
```

However, seeing you have 15 generically named separate columns in your database, I suspect you have much bigger problems with your data model than just this one slow query...